# Serializing a RandomAccessSparseVector in Mahout

Tags: java, serialization, hadoop, mahout

I'm loading data into a `RandomAccessSparseVector` in Mahout 0.7, and I don't know how to serialize it. If I were using a `VectorWritable` I'd be able to use `SequenceFile.Writer` as so:

```
writer = new SequenceFile.Writer(
    fs, conf, new Path("filename"), LongWritable.class,
    VectorWritable.class);
```

There is no `RandomAccessSparseVectorWritable`, unfortunately.

One option is to forget sparse vectors altogether and load the data into a `VectorWritable` and serialize it. I'd like to avoid this because it is sloppy to manually enter a load of zeroes into a `VectorWritable` and then take up a bunch of room on disk when serializing. `RandomAccessSparseVector` also can't be cast to `VectorWritable`.

If it is of any use, I've set

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("io.serializations",
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization");
```

so that Hadoop knows how to serialize.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is really simple. After a while of fruitless digging through the API docs, I happened upon a useful forum post. `VectorWritable` is not a vector type but a vector wrapper for serializing.  Before, I was trying to write a `RandomAccessSparseVector` generated like so

```
RandomAccessSparseVector vect = new RandomAccessSparseVector(columns);
```

by calling

```
key = new LongWritable(foo)
RandomAccessSparseVector vect = new RandomAccessSparseVector(columns);
writer.append(key, vect)
```

All I needed was to call

```
writer.append(key, new VectorWritable(vect))
```